# When I tried to access a secured web service through spring client, I'm getting an exception : signingKey cannot be null?

Tags: wss, spring-ws

```
Caused by: com.sun.xml.wss.XWSSecurityException: java.lang.NullPointerException: signingKey cannot be null
    at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.dsig.SignatureProcessor.sign(SignatureProcessor.java:328)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.filter.SignatureFilter.process(SignatureFilter.java:313)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.HarnessUtil.processWSSPolicy(HarnessUtil.java:83)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.HarnessUtil.processDeep(HarnessUtil.java:237)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.SecurityAnnotator.processMessagePolicy(SecurityAnnotator.java:162)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.SecurityAnnotator.secureMessage(SecurityAnnotator.java:137)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.misc.XWSSProcessor2_0Impl.secureOutboundMessage(XWSSProcessor2_0Impl.java:96)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: signingKey cannot be null
```

Comment: Can you be more specific on your setup? It might be relate to the way you define you keystores/truststores and WSDL policies.

Answer (score 0):

Google gave this: http://forum.springsource.org/archive/index.php/t-50083.html.